# Reduce text width to 0 (internal wire)

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object, wireframe

I'm unable to find even a starting point to this problem, so any guidance of any sort would be awesome. First a short paragraph on fonts.

#### Fonts

From what I know, fonts in general are described as (close oriented) curves. Multiple curves describe the area that should be filled, as shown here :

[image: Example of curves describing a font]

Here we have 2 curves for <kbd>A</kbd>, but for example there could be 3 for a <kbd>B</kbd>. Note that in my example, the width of the font is constant but that's not always the case (for example <kbd>a</kbd> in the next image)

#### My goal

I'm trying to go from this shape, which is basically a line with thickness, to really just a line. A sort of collapse of the width of the font to a wire text as below :

[image: The process]

On the left is the process I want to achieve. On the right is a comparison before/after.

This process looks to me complex. For example, fonts are described as closed curves which
wouldn't be guaranteed in this wire-like state. Think of an <kbd>i</kbd>, where the bottom part would be just a line. To show you just one case where the process can become complex, let's take a look at the top of an <kbd>A</kbd> :

[image: Edge-case of top part of "A" letter]

The original <kbd>A</kbd> (orange) have unrelated topologies, between the outter curve (2 points) and the inner curve (1 point). The process should probably create 2 points. I feel like there are a lot of edge-cases like that, for example how do you collapse a <kbd>.</kbd> (initially a circle/disc) : to a smaller circle, or to a point, ...

#### My conditions

1. To be somewhat procedural
2. So, no manual modelling
3. To work for this kind of fonts (basically, sans-serif with solid borders :

[image: Type of fonts expected]

**I would consider as acceptable answer if the solution only work for constant-width fonts (like most of the examples above). It would already be a great starting point.**

4. To work for letters and numbers, if possible with usual characters too (<kbd>,</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> ...).

#### My question

Do you have any idea how to approach that problem ? Is there an easy way to achieve that ? Otherwise, would you know the name of a method or algorithm ? Or do you think it's impossible to implement a general solution, under these conditions ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading me !

Comment: There are may different fonts and many different characters. I don't think there is a practical general solution☻Character "A" does not represent the actual problem, which is way more complex.

Comment: I mean... what do you do with [this one](https://www.1001fonts.com/disappeared-without-a-trace-font.html), or [this one](https://www.1001fonts.com/retro-signed-font.html), or even [this one](https://www.1001fonts.com/foxy-glam-font.html)?.. This cannot even be done manually.

Comment: I was thinking of simpler fonts, I've updated the question with a few examples. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys If you have an answer even for just one font of your choosing, I'll gladly give the bounty. I'm searching for a starting point, so that I can extend it myself. Starting point that I haven't found yet.

Comment: I suspect this to be a way more complex problem than it seems at first. It might be easier to do it manually. What do you need this for? Maybe it's possible to solve the original problem easier.

Comment: I know it can appear quicker to model it manually. I'm not looking for speed but for procedurality. I think I should probably open another question with my specific application, otherwise my question will become too broad. Basically, I wanted to have animated electricity-like text, where the width is constant but with small scale noise offset. It has been the 3rd or 4th time I had to kill a creative idea because I would have needed a 0-width text. I still hope there is an solution or a half-solution to this.

Comment: @Lutzi This is the best I could come up with in the hope of getting a general solution: https://blend-exchange.com/b/xYvorWeE

Comment: @ugorek Please consider posting it as an answer (and maybe get the bounty). That's an interesting solution ! Some imperfections but it looks like it's working. Thank you :)