How to make a mesh thinner?
I'm making a neon sign. My idea is that I have some extruded text, but inside that text is the neon light. I converted the mesh to a curve, but I don't want it to be an outline of that extruded text. I want it to be centered inside.
Is there a way I can reduce the thickness/boldness of a mesh? It's text but it isn't a text object. I made the text in paint.net and converted it to an SVG.


I asked the same question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315620/reduce-text-width-to-0-internal-wire. No simple or trivial solution. You could expand/contract the border with GN but you'd quickly get artifacts.

Man...wish there was something easier. I ended up making a thinner version of the text in paint.net but its not perfect.

@ENunn When I look at Lutzi's question it seems the goal there is to get the backbone or what it is called, so just a single line in the center... but you just want to inset the faces a bit as it seems? So why not use the Inset tool on a mesh object?
